# Dart Sass Transformer Output Directory

Tags: sass, dart

I am using Dart with the SASS pub build transformer. Does anyone know how to specify the output directory for compiled css files? I have tried a number of option keys ('output', 'put'), looked over docs, and haven't been able to figure out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is such an option https://bitbucket.org/evidentsolutions/dart-sass/src/186ea54c0664637520eb85f5d8be19f5691f8427/lib/src/transformer_options.dart?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: Thanks, I did see that, but I was in denial that a compiler didn't have an option to specify an output directory.

Comment: This is probably a limitation of pub transformers. You could use the sass file watcher instead.

Comment: Yeah, so we are using the Webstorm file watcher for local compilation, but we need something more consistent for deployment (we are also tracking our css files in git, which is problematic and needs to stop).  Rather than setup a file watcher on our dev server, I was told to use pub build, which made sense at the time.  I may still try to make it work.

Comment: I suggest creating an issue in the GitHub repo of the transformer. The author might not read this SO question (please crosslink when you do)